# What does "virtualization of the OS" mean?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand the virtualization(Container) technology. And, based on one video I saw, containers virtualize Operating System while VM virtualize the hardware.

What does virtualization of Operating System mean?

Comment: `containers virtualize Operating System` I don't think that's true. For example, if you're running Docker on linux, and a program in a container makes a system call to the kernel, that system call is not being handled by a second copy of the linux kernel, as would happen if that program were running in a VM.

Comment: This seems like a question you could answer by more research on containers versus VMs. Terminology gets a little confusing when dealing with this topic - better to understand the basic principles of how it works. I probably only say that since I'm not so sure I like the term "OS Virtualization" a lot here. Anyhoo, here's another explanation to compare with the video you saw [containers-vs-vms](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/containers-vs-vms) and here (with nice pictures): [containers-vs-vm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/containers-vs-vm)